# Blank resultset when trying to connect with MySQL Database through node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

**Issue Details**

Blank resultset when trying to connect with MySQL Database through node.js. I am using Window 8.1 with XAMPP for PHP and MySQL. I can confirm that the mysql is accessible on my machine. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

**[I am following this article to install mysql package in node.js.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql)**

> 1. Ran this command : npm install node-mysql
> 2. Wrote below code.

```
var db = require('node-mysql');
var DB = db.DB;

var box = new DB({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'homework',
    connectionLimit: 50
});

var basicTest = function(cb) {
    box.connect(function(conn, cb) {
        cps.seq([
            function(_, cb) {
                conn.query('select * from tbluser limit 1', cb);
            },
            function(res, cb) {
                console.log(res);
                cb();
            }
        ], cb);
    }, cb);
};



basicTest(function(){
    console.log("Done");
});
```

**Below is the blank output. It shows nothing.**

I am expecting the record from database. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the script you must call your basicTest with a callback.
Try this:

```
var db = require('node-mysql');
var DB = db.DB;

var box = new DB({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'homework',
    connectionLimit: 50
});

var basicTest = function(cb) {
    box.connect(function(conn, cb) {
        cps.seq([
            function(_, cb) {
                conn.query('select * from tbluser limit 1', cb);
            },
            function(res, cb) {
                console.log(res);
                cb();
            }
        ], cb);
    }, cb);
};

basicTest(function(){
    console.log("Done");
});
```

Comment: That is the same thing. I am sorry, I forgot to add the calling part. But still nothing happening. Output is blank.

Comment: Then result from your database is empty. Are you sure you are using correct connection configuration?

Comment: In case, I use `var db = require('mysql');` by installing `mysql` package, everything works. But, does not work when using package `npm install node-mysql`, Any idea why? Are you able to see records your side using `npm install node-mysql` ?